# Burndown doesn't match Sprint Capacity widget

Tags: azure-devops

Can anyone explain why our sprint burndown does not match the "Sprint Capacity" dashboard widget?

**Burndown:**

[image: Burndown]

**"Sprint Capacity" dashboard widget:**

[image: Sprint Capacity Widget]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Sprint Capacity, "347.75" means the remained hours for incomplete tasks. It is consistent with the "Remaining Work" in Burndown chart. And the "481" means the total capacity hours in this sprint while the "Available Capacity" in Burndown chart shows the remained capacity hours by the end of that day. So on 12/4/2015, you only see about 400 hours rather than 481 hours since the working hours on that day has been excluded.